# read attribute using XDocument and LINQ

Tags: linq, attributes, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to parse a rss feed. I can get the elements out, but whatever i try, i cant get the attributes!

This is how the rss feed (xml) looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>nu.nl - Algemeen</title>
    <copyright>Copyright (c) 2010, nu.nl</copyright>
    <link>http://www.nu.nl/algemeen/</link>
    <language>nl</language>
    <description>nu.nl Rich Site Summary</description>
    <pubDate>Sat, 16 Oct 2010 08:36:37 +0200</pubDate>
              <item>
        <title>Jason W. keert zich af van moslimextremisme</title>
        <link>http://www.nu.nl/binnenland/2357342/jason-w-keert-zich-af-van-moslimextremisme.html</link>
        <guid>http://www.nu.nl/binnenland/2357342/index.html</guid>
        <description>AMSTERDAM - Het vermeende lid van de Hofstadgroep Jason W. heeft het moslimextremisme naar eigen zeggen de rug toegekeerd.</description>
                <related>
            <b>Gerelateerd nieuws:</b><br />
                                    - <a href="http://www.nu.nl/binnenland/2293903/nieuw-proces-leden-hofstadgroep.html">Nieuw proces tegen leden Hofstadgroep</a><br />
                                    - <a href="http://www.nu.nl/binnenland/2175558/proces-hofstadgroep-moet.html">Proces Hofstadgroep moet over</a><br />
                                    - <a href="http://www.nu.nl/algemeen/2073580/eu-hof-verwerpt-beroep-van-lid-hofstadgroep.html">EU-hof verwerpt beroep van lid Hofstadgroep</a><br />
                    </related>
                <pubDate>Sat, 16 Oct 2010 08:36:36 +0200</pubDate>
        <category>Algemeen</category>
                <enclosure url="http://media.nu.nl/m/m1cz4nqakofe_t.jpg" type="image/jpeg" />      </item>
```

The attribute i'm trying to get is the 'enclosure url'.

This is my try:

```
private IEnumerable<Channel> getChannelQuery(XDocument xdoc)
    {

        return from channels in xdoc.Descendants("channel")
            select new Channel
            {
                Title = channels.Element("title") != null ? channels.Element("title").Value : "",
                Link = channels.Element("link") != null ? channels.Element("link").Value : "",
                Description = channels.Element("description") != null ? channels.Element("description").Value : "",
                //PubDate = channels.Element("pubDate") != null ? channels.Element("pubDate").Value : "",
                //Enclosure = channels.Element("enclosure ") != null ? channels.Element("enclosure").Value : "",
                Items = from items in channels.Descendants("item")
                    select new Item
                    {
                        Title = items.Element("title") != null ? items.Element("title").Value : "",
                        Link = items.Element("link") != null ? items.Element("link").Value : "",
                        Description = items.Element("description") != null ? items.Element("description").Value : "",
                        Guid = (items.Element("guid") != null ? items.Element("guid").Value : ""),
                        PubDate = (items.Element("pubDate") != null ? items.Element("pubDate").Value : ""),
                        Enclosure = (items.Attribute("url") != null ? items.Attribute("url").Value : "")
                    }
            };
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: how did you do that jon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't it

```
Enclosure = (items.Element("enclosure").Attribute("url") != null ? items.Element("enclosure").Attribute("url").Value : "")
```

?

Comment: yes that worked! But how? enclosure isn't an element is it? shouldn't it be an attribute?

Comment: @Yustme: I think you are confused because the enclosure is a self-closing tag, it is still an element as it starts with <

Comment: ah okay, its a while since i played with xml. thanks for clearing that up for me!